# How do you build a simple Eclipse editor with a select set of plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

Does anyone have a tutorial for building a custom Eclipse IDE with only a select set of plugins?

I am assuming I would need:
eclipse.exe
some plugins from the plugins directory, some folders from the features directory.

My goal is to only include the basic text editor and maybe a couple of other utilities.

(Yes, I could just use notepad/textpad but there is a project I am working on where a "lighter" version of Eclipse would be useful).

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse Rich Client Platform (RCP) is meant exactly for this - building applications that are based on Eclipse without including the whole IDE.

Here are a [lot of resources about it](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform)

Here is an example of an [editor based on RCP](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-text/development/rcp/examples/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Create a product configuration file (New -> Other -> Plug-in Development -> Product Configuration).

You can base the product on either plug-ins or features (if you want both, go with features, you'll get the features and their included plug-ins).  You define the product or application to launch on startup and there are options for splash screens and branding.

As an example you can also create a new plug-in project and in the wizard say yes to "Would you like to create a rich client application".  You can then choose a template.

You can export this product from the UI and it will automatically take care of including the executables for you.  You can also build it headlessly (see the [help](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_product_build.htm)) which will require the deltapack (3.4.2 version is [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.4.2-200902111700/download.php?dropFile=eclipse-3.4.2-delta-pack.zip)) to get the launchers.